# Clear Cell Contents of range if Contes = 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to clear a cell contents of a range based.
I think I'm nearly there.

```
    Dim R As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow)
        For Each R In myRange
        If R = 0 Then
        cell.ClearContents
        End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: `ClearContents` is a method if the `Range` object. Both `myRange` and each `R` are range objects. Therefore both `myRange.ClearContents` and `R.ClearContents` will work. You have not declared "Cell" as anything. Therefore it can't be a range. Therefore it doesn't have a `ClearContents` method you could invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your cell reference. Change `cell.` to `R.` `R` is the cell in the range that you are looping through so if `R = 0`, clear it.

```vb
Sub clearR()
    Dim R As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = Range("Y2:Y" & lastRow)
    For Each R In myRange
        If R = 0 Then
            R.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect did exactly what I wanted. Cleared the range of everything that was a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution without a loop if column Y is not formula then this should work.

```
Sub clearR()
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).Replace 0, "", xlWhole
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find last row
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Clear replace 0 with nothing in the specific range
        .Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```