# Trying to Delete Rows with False Value in my Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty sure I'm nearly there. At the moment this deletes all rows.
I just want it to delete the rows identified as having the word `FALSE` in them.

```
Dim R As Range
Dim myRange As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set myRange = Range("U2:U" & LastRow)

For Each R In myRange
    If R.Value = "FALSE" Then
        Rows.Delete
    End If
Next
```

I've also tried using the below code but it did not help.

````
Dim R As Range
Dim myRange As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set myRange = Range("U2:U" & LastRow)

For Each R In myRange
    If R = "False" Then
        R.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next```
````

Here's a screenshot of how the value is stored.
It's was a field that was stripped from a Vlookup and converted to a value.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear Cell Contents of range if Contes = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64095962/clear-cell-contents-of-range-if-contes-0)

Comment: No It doesn't. I'll add to the original post, also what I've tried with that. Sorry.

Comment: Does this answer? [Delete row based on partial text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text) No need to loop. You can use `Autofilter` to delete the relevant rows in 1 go.

Comment: BTW how is the "False" stored in the cell? As a String or as a Boolean value? Perhaps you can add a screenshot?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Image added. It's a string?

Comment: no it is not a string.. one moment. posting an anaswer

Comment: @SiddharthRout I reworked your "Delete row based on partial text" and it looks like it is doing something, and doesn't error, but doesn't actually delete the FALSE rows.

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with `False` can be tricky so I created an example for you as shown below.

[image]

As I recomendded in the comments, do not use a loop. Use `Autofilter` as mentioned in [Delete row based on partial text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-partial-text)

Try this

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchValue As Boolean
    Dim lRow As Long

    SearchValue = False
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
        With .Range("U1:U" & lRow)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchValue
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Final result:**

[image]

**Note:**

If this works for you, I will close this question as a duplicate but retain this answer as it shows how to deal with Boolean and Boolean (Stored as string) values.

Comment: I appreciate this approach as this is faster than others answer.

Comment: @Siddharth Fantastic - this worked! Really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    Dim LastRow As Long, cell As Range
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("U2:U" & LastRow)
        If cell.Value = "False" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note: ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet is not necessary it is better to give proper reference.

Comment: Sorry @Amit This does not work either.

Comment: If you share your Excel File with Dummy Data I can do my best.

Comment: Or you can also Try this with replacing the "False" with "FALSE" or False.

Comment: @Amit Your answer will fail because you need to loop through from bottom to top as your are deleting row. After deleting rows bottoms rows shift to up.

Comment: @Harun24HR Sorry I Forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on below sub.

```
Sub RemoveWithFalse()
Dim rng As Range, rws As Long, i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("U1:U" & LastRow)
  rws = rng.Rows.Count
  
  For i = rws To 1 Step (-1)
    If rng.Rows(i) = False Then rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
  Next
  
  Set rng = Nothing
  
End Sub
```

> If `Column U` is formatted as `Text` then use below line

```
If rng.Rows(i) = "FALSE" Then rng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: this was close, but deleted any rows containing FALSE. Changing to the text format didn't work either.

Comment: Then you need to use bottom most line.